# How tell wget to only download files within a specific path

Tags: linux, wget

I am trying to download the contents of a website, but since this website is in more than one language, I faced a problem. the structure of the site is as follows:

```
Mysite.com
fr.Mysite.com
ar.Mysite.com
...
```

I just want to download files in the Arabic domain (ar.Mysite.com), but using -r option it also downloads the contents of other languages. How can I say wget to recursively download the files, but just the files within a specific domain?

Answer (score -1):

The `--no-parent` option does what you want, if I understand the question.  It limits queries to those that lie underneath the "directory" specified by the original URL.

Comment: I think --no-parent will prevent downloading the contents of English files (which are in the root directory: Mysite.com). But how about other directories? I mean, I want to download just Arabic Files, but it also downloads French files (which are in fr.Mysite.com). Does --no-parent option do this?

Comment: When you explain it that way, I don't think there can be a solution.  How would wget know that you want to follow links to one other hostname but not all of them?  It's not magic.